# How can I teach Mathematica a specific f[x]==g[x]?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

Specifically, I know that `JacobiCN[EllipticF[I x, 2], 2]==Cosh[x]` for complex x (e.g., check with series expansion in x about x=0), but `FullSimplify` will neither confirm the identity nor simplify the left side to the right side.

How can I "teach" MMA to simplify the above to `Cosh[x]`? There are a number of other Jacobi Elliptic function identities that I would like to "teach" MMA in order to make life easy.

CLARIFICATION: I would like the following to yield `Cosh[x]`

```
FullSimplify[JacobiCN[EllipticF[I x], 2], 2]
```

I would like it to do so for any argument, not just x, since I don't know in advance what the argument will be. For example,

```
FullSimplify[JacobiCN[EllipticF[I y], 2], 2]==Cosh[y]

FullSimplify[JacobiCN[EllipticF[I Sin[a]^b, 2], 2]==Cosh[Sin[a]^b]
```

should both yield True. x,y,a,b, etc. are generally complex numbers.

Comment: It would be useful you post the code you have tried. In a hurry, I would use in `FullSimplify` the option `Assumptions->JacobiCN[EllipticF[I x, 2], 2]==Cosh[x]` or in your expression to be simplified the rule `/. JacobiCN[EllipticF[I x, 2], 2]->Cosh[x]`

Answer (score 3):

you may want to play with `TransformationFunctions`

```
Clear[t]
t[JacobiCN[EllipticF[I x_, 2], 2]] := Cosh[x]
FullSimplify[JacobiCN[EllipticF[I y, 2], 2], 
 TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, t}]
```

> Cosh[y]

```
FullSimplify[JacobiCN[EllipticF[I Sin[a]^b, 2], 2], 
 TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, t}]
```

> Cosh[Sin[a]^b]

note it seems you could do this as well (cleaner):

```
t[JacobiCN[EllipticF[x_, 2], 2]] := Cosh[-I x]
```

you should verify correctness though.

Answer (score 1):

For instance:

```
JacobiCN[EllipticF[I Sin[a x + Sqrt[3]], 2], 2] /. 
JacobiCN[EllipticF[I x_, 2], 2] ->  Cosh[x]
```

which returns

```
Cosh[Sin[Sqrt[3] + a x]]
```

However, I am puzzled as MMA does not recognised the equality between the terms you are trying to make equal:

```
JacobiCN[EllipticF[I y, 2], 2] === Cosh[y]

(* False *)
```

If so, maybe this could be the reason why `FullSimplify` does not work.

Comment: There's some serious whackiness here:


    `xne = FindInstance[JacobiCN[EllipticF[I x, 2], 2] != Cosh[x], x][[1]]`
    `(* {x -> 899/10 + (578 I)/5} *)`


But, in fact, they agree to 50 places:


    `N[Cosh[x] /. xne, 50]`
    `(* -4.4321692141504986119689214681396443885366308222468*10^38 + 3.2925662127511753354382365101127987767774575518821*10^38 I *)`
    `N[JacobiCN[EllipticF[I x, 2], 2] /. xne, 50]`
    `(* -4.4321692141504986119689214681396443885366308222468*10^38 + 3.2925662127511753354382365101127987767774575518821*10^38 I *)`

Comment: Notably, machine precision introduces an error of approximately $10^{38}$ in the absolute value of the difference, so it might be that the comparison operators are being careless with error management when converting to real numbers to determine `<` and `==`. Perhaps a bug? Using that `x` value, and calling LHS-RHS `v`, `Re[v]<0` and `Im[v]>0`, according to Mathematica.

Comment: I'm not sure this is relevant, but when JacobiXX[u,m] should return a real result, it returns that real plus a very small (choppable) imaginary part, so Chop[JacobiXX[u,m]] is the more accurate estimate of XX[u,m].